# Multiple citations with pages using BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, citing

How can I do multiple citations with page numbers using bibLaTeX/biber?

I have tried `\cite[2,3,4]{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: To what reference is associated page 2? Such citations are ambiguous.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use the multicite version of `\cite`:

```
\cites{ref1}[2]{ref2}[3]{ref3}[4]{ref4}
```

This will roughly give the following output:

```
<label1>; <label2>, p. 2; <label3>, p. 3; <label4>, p. 4
```

In general `\cites` takes arguments of the form

```
\cites(<multipre>)(<multipost>)[<pre>][<post>]{key}[<pre>][<post>]{key}...
```

where the first two arguments `(<multipre>)(<multipost>)` serve as an "overall" pre- and post-notes and the remaining arguments can be repeated as necessary. Citations are printed in the order given with compressed citation labels depending on the style.

For further details refer to material on "qualified citation lists" in the biblatex manual.

Comment: No problem. About your search - I am not surprised. The pertinent sections in the manual unfortunately use the term "multicite" and never "multiple citations".

Comment: cool, works also for \parencites 8)

Comment: Just to clarify, the case of OP is a bit special, for there is no prenote (e.g. like "p.~x" or "Thm.~Y") for his/her first entry. To get something like "[16, p. 383, 5, p. 179]" where 16 and 5 are two keys,one should use `\cites[p.~383]{key1}[p.~179]{key2}`. It might be obvious at second look, but I spent some time re-arranging my arguments :-)

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but what is the relevant package for `\cites`?

Comment: @ jamesh625 biblatex package.

Answer (score 9):

For those looking for the same feature, but in regular BibTex here's a working solution:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\citecomment}[2][]{\citen{#2}#1\citevar}
\newcommand{\citeone}[1]{\citecomment{#1}}
\newcommand{\citetwo}[2][]{\citecomment[,~#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\citevar}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{;~\citeone}{\@ifnextchar[{;~\citetwo}{]}}}
\newcommand{\citefirst}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\citeone}{\@ifnextchar[{\citetwo}{]}}}
\newcommand{\cites}{[\citefirst}
\makeatother
```

Which you can use like this

```
\cites[p.1]{ref1}{ref2}[chap.3]{ref3}
```

to get an output similar to

```
[<label1>, p.1; <label2>; <label3>, chap.3]
```

Comment: Puuuh, somthing that works for me. Takes me around 2 hours to find it. but thank you!

Comment: This! Note that `\citen` will not update according to the citation style but always print the number. Thus, the solution will not work for similar problems like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164208/multiple-citations-with-individual-page-numbers-using-natbib). Anyway, by replacing `\citen` with `\citenum` in the above code, the solution can be reused for natbib as well.