# How to cite two references and include their pages with natbib?

Tags: citing, natbib

```
\cite[p.~11]{Author1:2003a}
```

This inserts the number of page only for one author like "(Author1, 2003, p. 11)"

However, I would like something like "(Author1, 2003, p. 11, Author2, 2003, p. 22)"

Any idea?

Comment: Since you have some responses to previous question that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: @MarcoDaniel thanks for your advice, I started and will follow it.

Comment: With `biblatex` it is possible: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18911/8666

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The optional argument of the natbib citation commands -- `[p. 11]` in your first example -- is presumably specific to that citation. Mixing/combining the contents of the various optional arguments is likely going to confuse readers (and quite possibly you, the author, as well!) terribly.

You could achieve what you're looking for by issuing the command

```
 (\citealp[p. 11]{author1:2003}, \citealp[p. 22]{author2:2003})
```

Note that the output may be more easily parsable by your readers if you use a semicolon rather than a comma between the two `\citealp` commands.

Comment: A semicolon between the two may help, but I agree that this is probably confusing the reader.

Comment: @egreg: I did contemplate using a semicolon instead of a comma to separate the two `\citealp` commands, but decided to produce the look-and-feel that the OP asked for. I'll add a sentence suggesting the use of a semicolon.