# Cite multiple authors with page references

Tags: citing, natbib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple citations with pages using BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18910/multiple-citations-with-pages-using-biblatex)

How can I best include citations with multiple authors and page references? That is, I would like the output to look similar to this:

> This has been discussed by Anderson and Jones in multiple places (cf.
>   Anderson 1985:87, 1986a:123, 1986b:245, Jones 1989:100, 2000a:24,
>   2000b:45).

I'm currently using `natbib`, but I'm not tied to that if something else would be better.

Comment: The answer is really style/citation guide dependent.  Once you know the style (APA, MLA, etal) then just research the appropriate manual.  This will also guide you in selecting the appropriate BibTeX style.

Comment: I don't quite understand how that will help me. I know how I want the citations (the style) to look - I want to be able to cite multiple authors with page references, just as indicated in my question. Knowing that (or finding a style manual telling me that) doesn't help me knowing how to implement that in LaTeX code.

Comment: I think the best solution will be the usage of `biblatex`. I don't know whether there is a 100% identical style but `biblatex` allows your to modify the default settings very simple.

Comment: I've marked as a dupe, as the best plan is probably to use `bibltex` (I don't think `natbib` can do this). However, it's borderline: ask for reopening if you'd prefer to look for a `natbib` solution.

Comment: Personally I have migrated to `biblatex`, so closing the question doesn't matter to me. But this question is not a duplicate, because the other question specifically asks how to do it with `biblatex`, whereas I am asking how to do it with `natbib` and BibTeX. To assist others who have the same question, it would be better to just answer that it cannot be done (if that's indeed the case).

Comment: I only voted to close because you stated *"I'm currently using `natbib`, but I'm not tied to that if something else would be better."*

Comment: That's fine, but it doesn't change the fact that the question is not a duplicate. I would've preferred an answer along the lines of "it cannot be done with `natbib` and BibTeX, you should use `biblatex`", with a link to the alleged duplicate. [This is not a very important discussion anymore, so I'll end my contribution to it here]

Comment: I agree with Sverre. For the natbib case, the answer can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/how-to-cite-two-references-and-include-their-pages-with-natbib?noredirect=1&lq=1). @lockstep, consider changing your vote, and/or marking this as duplicate of the answer I have just linked.