# Multiple citations with references

Tags: citing

Using `\cite`, is it possible to do something like:

`\cite[Theorem A; Theorem B]{1 ; 2}` to generate [1,Theorem A ; 2, Theorem B]?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you use `biblatex` you can use `\cites[Theorem A]{sigfridsson}[Theorem B]{worman}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910/35864. For `natbib` a slightly less elegant workaround is possible https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166097/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184223/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324882/35864.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us if you employ a citation managment package, e.g., `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: @moewe - Nice cross-references to earlier `natbib`-based solutions! Since those use either authoryear or alpha-style citation call-outs, they may not be immedialtely applicable to the OP's needs, which involve numeric-style citation callouts. I've therefore gone ahead and posted a new `natbib`-based answer which is designed to generate numeric-style citation callouts.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `natbib` citation management package and use a bibliography style that's capable of generating numeric-style citation callouts, you could achieve your formatting objective along the lines shown in the following example.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{uv,author="U and V",year=3001}
@misc{xy,author="X and Y",year=3002}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
[\citealp[Theorem A]{uv}; \citealp[Theorem B]{xy}]
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```