# Ordering Natbib Citations Which Include Page Numbers by Referencing Number

Tags: citing, natbib, multiple-citations

I am currently working on citing multiple citations with page numbers and want to order the citations by their reference number similar to [this link](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23682). I am currently using LaTex I found from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166097/natbib-multiple-citations-with-page-numbers-in-one-bracket) to help me write `\citetext{\citealp{ref2}; \citealp[pg.200]{ref1}}`, however, it does not appear to put them in order. My current commands are:

```
\usepackage[square, numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
I would like to order these citations by reference number \citetext{\citealp{ref2}; \citealp[pg.200]{ref1}}.
 
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{bibfile}
 
\end{document}
```

When I use `\cite{ref2,ref1}` the command correctly displays these citations in order as `[1,2]` but when I write them as I have it above, I get `[2;1,pg.200]`. Is it possible to automatically make them `[1,pg.200;2]`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you not simply put ref1 first if you want it to appear first? Do you have a very long list of citations that you need to order?

Comment: Yes, I have a more extensive bibliography which would make that rather difficult.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the solution from the first post you mentioned unchanged? I.e. using only \cite ? From what I can see it looks like to me that should do what you want.

Comment: That works without page numbers. I was hoping I could provide the reference with the page number next to it, then move to the next reference.

Comment: Ah, I see. After some research it seems to me to be a major undertaking to implement this, or I'm just not seeing it. In any case, I must admit defeat.