# How to cite multiple authors with page references?

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib

I am writing my thesis and I am decided to use LaTeX (first time using it). Currently I am transferring my word document to latex. However, I don't know how to cite multiple authors with page references. For example, this is the output I am trying to achieve:

```
...cardiovascular disease, cancer and all-cause mortality 
(Wilmot et al., 2012: 2895–2905, Biswas et al., 2015: 123, Department of Health, 2010: 18).
```

This is the way I am currently doing it in Latex:

```
\citep[2895–2905,123,18]{wilmot2012,biswas2015,departmentofhealth2010}
```

However that results in that:

```
 (Wilmotet al., 2012; Biswas et al., 2015; Department of Health, 2010, 2895–2905,123,18)
```

Which makes me believe I am not providing the page references the right way or I am doing something else wrong. Any advice please?

Comment: This is one of the reasons to change to `biblatex`. It is a piece of cake with `biblatex`.

Comment: @Johannes_B how hard would you say would be the transition to biblatex from natbib?

Comment: Shouldn't be very hard. `biblatex` provides a compatibility mode for natbib. We have a *change to biblatex* Q/A somewhere on site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workarround from this question: [How to cite two references and include their pages with natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/how-to-cite-two-references-and-include-their-pages-with-natbib)

The above output can be achieved by using the following command:

```
(\citealp[2895–2905]{wilmot2012}; \citealp[123]{biswas2015}; \citealp[18]{departmentofhealth2010})
```