# Sorting citations using \cites command in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using `biblatex` for citations and bibliography. Now I often have lists of multiple citations, for which `biblatex` has the `\cites` command. Now I can get citations to automatically sort if I don't want page numbers, but I cannot get it right with page numbers.

What I want is all citation ordered chronological (oldest first). Is this possible, or must I just do this by hand?

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    useprefix=false,
    maxnames=2,
    firstinits=true,
    sortcites=true,
    uniquename=init,
    abbreviate=true,
    backend=biber,
    sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{tom1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {This book is from 2001},
  shorttitle = {2001},
}
@book{tom2,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {1999},
  title = {This book is from 1999},
  shorttitle = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
This one is corrent.\footnote{\Cites{tom1,tom2}.}
This one is corrent.\footnote{\Cite{tom1,tom2}.}


This one is incorrent.\footnote{\Cites{tom1}{tom2}.}
This one is incorrent.\footnote{\Cites[1]{tom1}[12]{tom2}.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically, the "incorrect" examples are correct as `\Cites` is a "multicite" command where each key is a stand-alone citation, not part of a list of citations. It's used precisely for manually ordering etc. You're right that there seems to be no cite ordering possible when you need to give pages for each key.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that they are technically correct. Just not exactly what I want... I was hoping there was a way to solve this.

Answer (score 12):

> Edited (2018-07-14) by moewe for `biblatex` >= v3.8. See the edit history for older `biblatex` versions.

The multicite commands take arbitrarily many arguments. They aren't designed to output a sorted citation list. It is possible to construct a two-pass version of `\cites` that will generate a sorted, qualified citation list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,sorting=ynt,sortcites]{biblatex}

\makeatletter

% original definition of \cites
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@cites}{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

% new definition
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\cbx@cite@wrapper\cbx@cites]{\cbx@cite}{}

% first pass saves keys, prenotes, postnotes
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@cite}
  {\csxdef{prenote:\thefield{entrykey}}{\thefield{prenote}}}
  {\listxadd\cbx@savekeys{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {}
  {\csxdef{postnote:\thefield{entrykey}}{\thefield{postnote}}}

% second pass outputs sorted citation list
\newrobustcmd{\cbx@cite@wrapper}[2]{%
  \def\cbx@savekeys{}%
  \def\cbx@citecall{#1}%
  #2\cbx@sortkeysinit\cbx@citesort\cbx@citecall}

% internal list of saved keys => sorted argument list
\def\cbx@citesort{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifinlist{##1}{\cbx@savekeys}
      {\protected@xappto\cbx@citecall{%
         [\csuse{prenote:##1}][\csuse{postnote:##1}]{##1}}}
      {}}%
  \dolistloop{\cbx@sortkeys}}

% internal list of sorted entry keys
\def\cbx@sortkeysinit{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}
    {}
    {\global\csletcs{cbx@sortkeys}{blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}}
\def\cbx@sortkeys{}

\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\cmd{cite}: \cite{companion,ctan,vangennep,markey} \\
\cmd{cites}: \cites[e.g.][10]{companion}{ctan}{markey}[10--11]{vangennep} \\
\cmd{Cites}: \Cites{ctan}{markey}[e.g.][5--10]{companion}[10--11]{vangennep}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this new version of `\cites` does not properly support `multiprenote` and `multipostnote` arguments of the form

```
\cites(<pre>)(<post>)...
```

A tidy resolution will probably warrant extension of `biblatex` internals. This is something we should consider as `\textcites` in the verbose styles suffers from the same limitation.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I've actually subsequently gone back and edited every use of \cites in my PhD... Oh well.

Comment: What is the answer for this thread? I am getting stuck with this issue too. I want to cite two authors in a row but wanting to add their appropriate page numbers.

Comment: @expling I've given an answer above. If you don't want the citations printed in the same order as the bibliography, then refer to this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910.

Comment: With `bibtex` this works, but when using `biber` I get `undefined control sequence \cbx@sortkeys`.

Comment: @user4514 That error resolves after you run biber the first time. To avoid it entirely replace the biber-specific code with `\ifcsundef{blx@slists@\the\c@refsection @entry@\blx@sorting}{}{\global\letcs{\cbx@sortkeys}{blx@slists@\the\c@refsection @entry@\blx@sorting}}`.

Comment: Thank you @Audrey. Could you also provide some pointers on how to do the same with the other citation commands (parencite, textcite,...)?

Comment: For an answer to my question see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/sorting-citations-using-cites-command-in-biblatex/70183#70183. For an updated version see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314199/sorting-citations-using-cites-command-in-biblatex-produces-error.

Comment: Using this with `style=numeric-comp` does not work unfortunately. For some reason the parentheses `[]` are missing.  I have no idea how to fix this.