# multiple citation with specific pages biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm using biblatex-apa and trying to get a multiple citation wit specific pages

What i want to get:

> (Author1,p.1; Author2,p.2)

my (working) workaround right now is this:

```
(\cite[][1]{author1}; \cite[][2]{author2})
```

but the problem here is the missing sortcites option

is there a way to do this with `\parencite` ?

when I'm trying to use `\cite` described like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18910/multiple-citations-with-pages-using-biblatex) does not work; my code:

```
\cite[][1]{author1}[][2]{author2}
```

neither does `\parencite` work

```
\parencite[][1]{author1}[][2]{author2}
```

Comment: The multicite versions have an **s** in their name, so `\cite` becomes `\cites`. There is `\parencites[1]{baez/article}[2]{baez/online}`, for sorting with `\parencites` (which is not possible out of the box) see [Sorting citations using \cites command in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65809/35864).

Comment: great - that fixed my problem - thank you very much