# Biblatex: Sorting citations in qualified citation list \parencites

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Following the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70183/56450, I was trying to get a correct sorting for keys in a `\parencites` command including pre- and post-notes. Is there an equivalent way to do it? All my attempts failed.

**MWE:**

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber%
           ,style=apa%
           ,maxcitenames=5%
           ,uniquename=full%
           ,sortcites%
           ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@incollection{Klieme,
    author = {Klieme, E.},
    title = {Titel},
    year = {2001},
}
@book{Clausen,
    author = {Clausen, M.},
    title = {Titel},
    year = {1998},
} 
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb+\parencite{Klieme,Clausen}+: \parencite{Klieme,Clausen}, correct sorting\\
\verb+\parencites{Klieme,Clausen}+: \parencites{Klieme,Clausen}, correct sorting\\
\verb+\parencites[vergl.][51]{Klieme}[114]{Clausen}+: \parencites[vergl.][51]{Klieme}[114]{Clausen}, wrong sorting

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s [great answer to *Sorting citations using `\cites` command in `biblatex`*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70183/35864) only redefines the `\cites` command, but adding support for other `\...cites` is surprisingly (or perhaps not surprisingly) easy.

For `\parencites` we only need two additional lines

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@parencites}[\mkbibparens]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\cbx@cite@wrapper\cbx@parencites]{\cbx@cite}{}
```

for `\textcites` analogously

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textcites}{\textcite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}[\cbx@cite@wrapper\cbx@textcites]{\cbx@cite}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber%
           ,style=authoryear%
           ,maxcitenames=5%
           ,uniquename=full%
           ,sortcites%
           ]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@parencites}[\mkbibparens]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\cbx@cite@wrapper\cbx@parencites]{\cbx@cite}{}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@textcites}{\textcite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}[\cbx@cite@wrapper\cbx@textcites]{\cbx@cite}{}

% original definition of \cites
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@cites}{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

% new definition
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\cbx@cite@wrapper\cbx@cites]{\cbx@cite}{}

% first pass saves keys, prenotes, postnotes
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@cite}
  {\csxdef{prenote:\thefield{entrykey}}{\thefield{prenote}}}
  {\listxadd\cbx@savekeys{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {}
  {\csxdef{postnote:\thefield{entrykey}}{\thefield{postnote}}}

% second pass outputs sorted citation list
\newrobustcmd{\cbx@cite@wrapper}[2]{%
  \def\cbx@savekeys{}%
  \def\cbx@citecall{#1}%
  #2\cbx@sortkeysinit\cbx@citesort\cbx@citecall}

% internal list of saved keys => sorted argument list
\def\cbx@citesort{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifinlist{##1}{\cbx@savekeys}
      {\protected@xappto\cbx@citecall{%
         [\csuse{prenote:##1}][\csuse{postnote:##1}]{##1}}}
      {}}%
  \dolistloop{\cbx@sortkeys}}

% internal list of sorted entry keys
\def\cbx@sortkeysinit{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}
    {}
    {\global\csletcs{cbx@sortkeys}{blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}}
\def\cbx@sortkeys{}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\parencite{wilde,sigfridsson}\\
\parencites{wilde,sigfridsson}\\
\parencites[vergl.][51]{wilde}[114]{sigfridsson}\\
\parencites{knuth:ct:c}{knuth:ct:b}{knuth:ct:a}

\noindent
\cite{wilde,sigfridsson}\\
\cite{wilde,sigfridsson}\\
\cites[vergl.][51]{wilde}[114]{sigfridsson}\\
\cites{knuth:ct:c}{knuth:ct:b}{knuth:ct:a}

\noindent
\textcite{wilde,sigfridsson}\\
\textcite{wilde,sigfridsson}\\
\textcites[vergl.][51]{wilde}[114]{sigfridsson}\\
\textcites{knuth:ct:c}{knuth:ct:b}{knuth:ct:a}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE: all citations are now sorted]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Maybe you could add a link to your answer to the original answer by [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey). I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @ccauet Since we mentioned the other question here quite extensively, the two questions are now linked via the "linked questions" on the right. So there is no need to add a comment to the other answer, I don't think.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of that option. Fine with me.