# Sorting citations using \cites command in biblatex produces error

Tags: biblatex, biber

Sorting citations using `\cites` command in biblatex with [Sorting citations using \cites command in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/sorting-citations-using-cites-command-in-biblatex) worked fine but doesn't work anymore with TexLive 2016.

```
Error produced with the minimal example of the above link:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \cbx@sortkeys 

l.49 ...mpanion}{ctan}{markey}[10--11]{vangennep} \\
```

Its's not just a wrong error message by running first time biber. There is no output for the intended sorted `\Cites` and `\cites` commands.

Anybody knows how to adjust the code for new TexLive 2016?

Comment: In which version did it work? With TL 2015 I get the same error as with 2016.

Comment: I guess it was with biblatex version pre-march 2016, however the proposed code should work with TeXLive 2016 or would need some changes. The problem stays the same: how can I sort multiple bib-entries with biblatex and biber and the cited comands?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and searched in the old and new `biblatex.sty` and related files.
I found where the definition of

```
{\global\letcs{\cbx@sortkeys}
     {blx@slists@\the\c@refsection @entry@\blx@sorting}}% Biber
```

in Audray's solution ([Sorting citations using \cites command in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70183/48680)) came from. This does not work with the actual biblatex, because some of the arguments used here are not defined anymore. I had to replace these lines with the definition found in the actual biblatex:

```
{\global\letcs{\cbx@sortkeys}
    {blx@slist@centry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}% Biber
```

It is still not the cleanest solution using the deep internals of biblatex, but it woks for me ...

Here a MWE. It is a patch of the MWE in Audrey's brilliant answer (so the credits still belong to him):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,sorting=ynt,sortcites]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
% original definition of \cites
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@cites}{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

% new definition
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\cbx@cite@wrapper\cbx@cites]{\cbx@cite}{}

% first pass saves keys, prenotes, postnotes
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@cite}
  {\csxdef{prenote:\thefield{entrykey}}{\thefield{prenote}}}
  {\listxadd\cbx@savekeys{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {}
  {\csxdef{postnote:\thefield{entrykey}}{\thefield{postnote}}}

% second pass outputs sorted citation list
\newrobustcmd{\cbx@cite@wrapper}[2]{%
  \def\cbx@savekeys{}%
  \def\cbx@citecall{#1}%
  #2\cbx@sortkeysinit\cbx@citesort\cbx@citecall}

% internal list of saved keys => sorted argument list
\def\cbx@citesort{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifinlist{##1}{\cbx@savekeys}
       {\protected@xappto\cbx@citecall{%
          [\csuse{prenote:##1}][\csuse{postnote:##1}]{##1}}}
       {}}%
  \dolistloop{\cbx@sortkeys}}

% internal list of sorted entry keys [patched to the original answer, new biblatex!]
\def\cbx@sortkeysinit{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@slist@centry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}
    {}
    {\global\letcs{\cbx@sortkeys}{blx@slist@centry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}}
\def\cbx@sortkeys{}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\textbackslash\texttt{#1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\cmd{cite}: \cite{companion,ctan,vangennep,markey} \\
\cmd{cites}: \cites[e.g.][10]{companion}{ctan}{markey}[10--11]{vangennep} \\
\cmd{Cites}: \Cites{ctan}{markey}[e.g.][5--10]{companion}[10--11]{vangennep}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, I did some more digging, it should work perfectly if you replace the definition of `\cbx@sortkeysinit` by `\def\cbx@sortkeysinit{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@slist@centry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}
    {\global\letcs{\cbx@sortkeys}{blx@slist@centry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}
    {}}` (mod line breaks). In version 3.5 this works for both `biblatex` and Biber from the first run without any errors. If you include that in your answer and write a full MWE I'd be more than happy to up-vote it.

Comment: @Michael: I must say that this was a little bit try and error, due to my medium LaTeX fu. I use this citation sorting in a different way. But I will adapt an example, and extend my answer.

Comment: I have modified the code a tiny bit to be a bit shorter. In all my tests it still behaved as expected. But if you find a problem with it, give me a shout and change it back.

Comment: Ah, and thank you for the MWE (+1)!