# citation call-outs separated with a semicolon

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using the following:

```
\citep[vgl. bspw. ][S. 380]{Bortz2006}\citep[S. 40]{Fayyad1996}\citep[S. 11]{Maimon2010}
```

to get the output:

> [vgl. bspw. BD06, S. 380][FPSS96, S. 40][MR10, S. 11]

Is it possible to separated the citation with a semicolon and not with a square bracket, like this:

> [vgl. bspw. BD06, S. 380; FPSS96, S. 40; MR10, S. 11]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please tell us (a) which bibliography style you employ and (b) the ways in which you've modified the `natbib` defaults. E.g., do you set the `square` option when loading the package?

Comment: maybe have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18911/36296, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164208/multiple-citations-with-individual-page-numbers-using-natbib or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166097/natbib-multiple-citations-with-page-numbers-in-one-bracket

Comment: i am using natbib with style lni \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{bibstyle/lni}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should replace

```
\citep[vgl.~bspw.][S.~380]{Bortz2006}\citep[S.~40]{Fayyad1996}\citep[S.~11]{Maimon2010}
```

with

```
\citetext{vgl. bspw. \citealp[S.~380]{Bortz2006}; \citealp[S.~40]{Fayyad1996}; 
\citealp[S.~11]{Maimon2010}}
```

Observe the use of `\citetext` and three `\citealp` instructions.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{lni} 
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}

\citep[vgl.~bspw.][S.~380]{Bortz2006}\citep[S.~40]{Fayyad1996}\citep[S.~11]{Maimon2010}

\medskip
\citetext{vgl. bspw. \citealp[S.~380]{Bortz2006}; \citealp[S.~40]{Fayyad1996}; \citealp[S.~11]{Maimon2010}}

\begin{thebibliography}{99} % just for this example
\bibitem[BD06]{Bortz2006} stuff

\bibitem[FPSS96]{Fayyad1996} stuff

\bibitem[MR10]{Maimon2010} stuff
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx, that is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I think the biblatex *multicite* command `\parencites` can be an easy solution to this problem.

After defining the `.bib` file, for example mybib.bib:

```
@incollection{Bortz2006,
  title     = {Quantitative Methoden der Datenerhebung},
  author    = {Bortz, J{\"u}rgen and D{\"o}ring, Nicola},
  booktitle = {Forschungsmethoden und Evaluation},
  pages     = {137--293},
  year      = {2006},
  publisher = {Springer}
}
@article{Fayyad1996,
  title     = {The KDD process for extracting useful knowledge from volumes of data},
  author    = {Fayyad, Usama and Piatetsky-Shapiro, Gregory and Smyth, Padhraic},
  journal   = {Communications of the ACM},
  volume    = {39},
  number    = {11},
  pages     = {27--34},
  year      = {1996},
  publisher = {ACM New York, NY, USA}
}
@article{Maimon2010,
  title     = {Data mining and knowledge discovery handbook},
  author    = {Maimon, Oded and Rokach, Lior},
  year      = {2010},
  publisher = {Springer}
}
```

You can then use the biblatex package in the `.tex` file as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{document}

Original output:

\citep[vgl. bspw. ][S. 380]{Bortz2006}\citep[S. 40]{Fayyad1996}\citep[S. 11]{Maimon2010}

\medskip
Output using \textbackslash parencites:

\parencites()()[vgl. bspw. ][S. 380]{Bortz2006}[S. 40]{Fayyad1996}[S. 11]{Maimon2010}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

With biblatex, run pdflatex + biber + pdflatex *2 to generate this output:

[image]