# Several citations in the same bracket

Tags: bibtex, citing

Suppose I make two citations at the same place

```
\cite{ref1}, \cite{ref2}
```

It would appear as

```
[1], [2]
```

Sometimes I see a reference like

```
[1, 2]
```

How is that done in TeX? Also, when should I use one over the other?

Comment: `\cite{key1,key2}`?

Comment: and with page number?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Multiple citations at the same place can be achieved with

```
\cite{ref1,ref2,...}
```

Some bibliographic styles (`ieee` for example)  turn multiple citations, i.e., [1,2] into [1], [2]. So, for the second part, it is a matter of the style used and customs.

Comment: Thank you! It is useful to realize that there should not be any space between the reference key and comma.

Comment: Whys does that matter? I get the same result both ways.

Comment: how to do this with page numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Just put multiple sources inside `\cite{}` argument field:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib} %Import the bibliography file

\begin{document}
multiple citation example: \cite{article1,article2,article3}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You can choose variant of the numeric style by specifying
option `citestyle=` inside `{biblatex}` package e.g.:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric-comp,]{biblatex}
```

[image]

There is also option for separate look:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric-verb,]{biblatex}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! If you use `biblatex-examples.bib` and pick entries from there anybody with Biblatex installed will be able to compile your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include page numbers, you can use BibLaTex's `\cites` command (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18911/255032)) or you can use BibTex with the `xparse` package and define your own command.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

% Takes up to 4 pairs of citations with optional page reference
\NewDocumentCommand{\multicite}{ogogogog}{%
    \citetext{%
        \IfValueT{#2}{%
            \IfValueT{#1}{\citealp[p.~#1]{#2}}%
            \IfNoValueT{#1}{\citealp{#2}}%
        }%
        \IfValueT{#4}{%
            ;
            \IfValueT{#3}{\citealp[p.~#3]{#4}}%
            \IfNoValueT{#3}{\citealp{#4}}%
        }%
        \IfValueT{#6}{%
            ;
            \IfValueT{#5}{\citealp[p.~#5]{#6}}%
            \IfNoValueT{#5}{\citealp{#6}}%
        }%
        \IfValueT{#8}{%
            ;
            \IfValueT{#7}{\citealp[p.~#7]{#8}}%
            \IfNoValueT{#7}{\citealp{#8}}%
        }%
    }
}
```

Example usage:
`\multicite[1]{Sjostrom2018}{Kerly2007}[3]{Winkler2019}`
leads to:

(Sjöström et al., 2018, p. 1; Kerly et al., 2007; Winkler und Roos, 2019, p. 3)