# Multiple citations condensed (different types) - FUQ

Tags: citing, abnt

---

This is a follow up question to [Several citations in the same bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172699/several-citations-in-the-same-bracket)

---

I want to cite multiple authors in the same `\cite{}` command instead of making each of them in separated. It works fine for citations of one specific kind (e.g. only articles) but I get error when mixing different types of publications (e.g. @book, @article, @THESIS).

`\cite{ref1}, \cite{ref2} ----> [1], [2]` OK!

`\cite{ref1,ref2} ----> [1, 2]` OK! for references of the same type (*ref1* and *ref2* being articles).

`\cite{ref1,ref2}  ---->    [1, 2]`    FAIL! for references of the different type (*ref1* being an article and *ref2* a thesis).

**How to solve that problem in my document?**

**OBS1**: This kind of reference is demanded in my thesis and I can't make it work. The citation package is `abntcite`.

**OBS2**: The style of document I am using is the standard of my institution (for PhD- and Master Thesis) and I don't know every detail of the documentclass. I can't even make a MWE that works. Still my attempt:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
  editor        = "J. C. Candy and G. C. Temes",
  title         = "Oversampling Delta-Sigma Data Converters Theory, Design and Simulation",
  publisher     = "{IEEE} Press.",
  location      = "New York",
  year          = "1992"
}
@article{article1,
  author        = "A. Castaldini and A. Cavallini and B. Fraboni and P. Fernandez and J. Piqueras",
  title         = "Midgap Traps Related to Compensation Processes in {CdTe} Alloys",
  journaltitle  = "Phys. Rev. B.",
  volume        = "56",
  number        = "23",
  year          = "1997",
  pages         = "14897-14900"
}
@article{article2,
  author        = "M. Coates and A. Hero and R. Nowak and B. Yu",
  title         = "Internet Tomography",
  journaltitle  = "IEEE J. Selected Areas Commun.",
  month         = 05,
  year          = "2002",
  note          = "to be published"
}
@THESIS{PhD1,
author = {Souza, J. R. de}, 
title = {Model},
school = inpebr,
year = {1997},
type = GESPhD,
address = sjc,
pages = {182},
note = { },
url = { }
}%
@MISC{oliveira,
   organization = {Instituto Tecnologico de Aeronautica - ITA},
   author   = {Oliveira, A. B. V. and  Walter, F.},
   title    = {Ionospheric equatorial anomaly studies during solar storms},
   year = {2005},
   url = { },
   urlaccessdate = { },
   note      = {In: International Union of Radio Science},
   address   = {São José dos Campos – SP},
   publisher = {Instituto Tecnológico de Aeronáutica},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,a4paper]{report}
\gdef\@tipocitacao{alf}
\DeclareOption{CitacaoNumerica}{%
    \typeout{-------------->Opcao: CitacaoNumerica}
    \gdef\@tipocitacao{num}
}
%%% Pacote da ABNTeX para referências dentro das normas %%%
\gdef\@sepbr{no} %% yes ou no para pagebackref em abnt-verbatim-entry

%\gdef\@tipocitacao{num}
\usepackage[debug,pagebackref=\@ativapbr,breaklinks,bookmarksopen=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=bblue,citecolor=bblue,urlcolor=bblue,filecolor=bblue,bookmarksnumbered=true,hyperindex=true,verbose=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[\@tipocitacao,abnt-emphasize=bf,abnt-etal-cite=2,abnt-etal-list=0,abnt-repeated-title-omit=yes,abnt-show-options=warn,abnt-verbatim-entry=\@sepbr,abnt-url-package=url]{abntcite}
%% Ativa bibliografia explicita (abnt-verbatim-entry) no formato bibtex
%% incompatível com o backref.sty por enquanto (ou um ou outro)
\gdef\@ativapbr{true} %% true or false : ativa pagebackref


\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\cite{book, article1, article2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is going to be very difficult to help without any idea what code you're using (e.g. where is `abntcite.sty` found?). However, you are missing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the preamble around the stuff which includes `@` in macro names.

Comment: Note that by default, this just works. It doesn't matter whether the entries have different types or not. It might not like the spaces, though.

Answer (score 2):

It may as well be that the OP has already finished her thesis by now, but here we go...

First of all I picked up on a few bibliography entries missing commas (`,`) and field delimeters (`{ }` or `" "`), so there's that. Also, I don't know if you defined it and forgot to put it in the MWE but there is no standard `bblue` color for `hyperref`, there's also that. Second (as far as I'm aware) you should use normal `\usepackage` for document writing instead of the class writing command `\RequirePackage`, the same could be said fo `\DeclareOption`.

Finally, to answer the question: I'm not quite sure what the problem is with `abntcite` and, honestly, I don't care. Neither should you, as it's deprecated. Both <s>`abntex`</s> class and <s>`abntcite`</s> package have new versions which are being properly maintained: [`abntex2`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2.pdf) and [`abntex2cite`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2cite.pdf) respectively, and should be used instead (both manuals are in pt_BR). With the proper modifications and the use of `abntex2cite` your code compiles just fine! Check it out.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
  editor        = "J. C. Candy and G. C. Temes",
  title         = "Oversampling Delta-Sigma Data Converters Theory, Design and Simulation",
  publisher     = "{IEEE} Press.",
  location      = "New York",
  year          = "1992"
}

@article{article1,
  author        = "A. Castaldini and A. Cavallini and B. Fraboni and P. Fernandez and J. Piqueras",
  title         = "Midgap Traps Related to Compensation Processes in {CdTe} Alloys",
  journaltitle  = "Phys. Rev. B.",
  volume        = "56",
  number        = "23",
  year          = "1997",
  pages         = "14897-14900"
}

@article{article2,
  author        = "M. Coates and A. Hero and R. Nowak and B. Yu",
  title         = "Internet Tomography",
  journaltitle  = "IEEE J. Selected Areas Commun.",
  month         = 05,
  year          = "2002",
  note          = "to be published"
}

@THESIS{PhD1,
author = "Souza, J. R. de", 
title = "Model",
school = "inpebr",
year = "1997",
type = "GESPhD",
address = "sjc",
pages = "182"
}

@MISC{oliveira,
   organization = "Instituto Tecnologico de Aeronautica - ITA",
   author   = "Oliveira, A. B. V. and  Walter, F.",
   title    = "Ionospheric equatorial anomaly studies during solar storms",
   year = "2005",
   note      = "In: International Union of Radio Science",
   address   = "São José dos Campos – SP",
   publisher = "Instituto Tecnológico de Aeronáutica"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[debug,
            pagebackref=true,
            breaklinks,
            bookmarksopen=true,
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            filecolor=blue,
            bookmarksnumbered=true,
            hyperindex=true,
            verbose=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[alf,
            abnt-emphasize=bf,
            abnt-etal-cite=2,
            abnt-etal-list=0,
            abnt-repeated-title-omit=yes,
            abnt-show-options=warn,
            abnt-verbatim-entry=no,
            abnt-url-package=url]{abntex2cite}

\begin{document}

\cite{book, article1, article2}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Furthermore, if you do not have the `abntex2cite` package consider upgrading your TeX distribution to the newest available. Or, if you know your ways, manually add the relevant classes/packages.