# Multiple citations with individual page numbers using apacite

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style, apa6

**Problem:**

Trying to cite two authors with each individual page numbers using the package **apacite**.

**(1) I tried the following:**

```
\cite[~p. 15-22]{atkin14} \cite[~p. 282]{rub14}
```

**(1) Outputs:**

```
(Atkinson & Fitzgerald, 2014, p. 15-22)(Rubin, 2014, p. 282)
```

**(2) I also tried:**

```
\cite[~p. 15-22, ~p. 282]{atkin14, rub14}
```

**(2) Outputs:**

```
(Atkinson & Fitzgerald, 2014; Rubin, 2014, p. 15-22, p. 282)
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
(Atkinson & Fitzgerald, 2014, p. 15-22; Rubin, 2014, p. 282)
```

Minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{rub14,
   author = {Rubin, Jared},
   title = {Printing and protestants: an empirical test of the role of printing in the Reformation},
   journal = {Review of Economics and Statistics},
   volume = {96},
   number = {2},
   pages = {270-286},
   year = {2014},
   type = {}
}

@book{atkin14,
   author = {Atkinson, Benedict  and Fitzgerald, Brian},
   title = {A short history of copyright: the genie of information},
   publisher = {Springer},
   address = {Cham},
   pages = {15-22},
   year = {2014},
   type = {}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\noindent One among many examples is the breakup of Europe's religious unity during the Protestant Reformation \cite[~p. 15--22, ~p. 282]{atkin14, rub14}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post not just some code snippets but a [Minimum Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that gives rise to the issue you're looking to fix. It's really important to know which packages you load, and which options you use when loading various packages. E.g., do you load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa`? By the way, the form of the augmented citation command should almost certainly be `\cite[p.~15--22]{atkin14}` rather than `\cite[~p. 15-22]{atkin14}`.

Comment: @Mico Added as requested.

Comment: I believe this answer solves this issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537201/34551

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the page-related references are specific to each entry, you can't use a single `\cite` command -- unless you want to risk confusing your readers...

Use the instruction

```
(\citeNP[pp.~15--22]{atkin14}; \citeNP[p.~282]{rub14})
```

to create two separate citation call-outs separated by a semicolon and encased in a single pair of round parentheses. The `NP` in `\citeNP` stands for "no parentheses".

By the way, you should apply care not to let BibTex lowercase the words `Protestants` and `Reformation`. Just encase the words in curly braces to inform BibTeX that they mustn't be converted to `protestants` and `reformation`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{rub14,
   author = {Rubin, Jared},
   title = {Printing and {Protestants}: An empirical test of the role of printing in the {Reformation}},
   journal = {Review of Economics and Statistics},
   volume = {96},
   number = {2},
   pages = {270--286},
   year = {2014},
}

@book{atkin14,
   author = {Atkinson, Benedict and Fitzgerald, Brian},
   title = {A Short History of Copyright: The Genie of Information},
   publisher = {Springer},
   address = {Cham},
   year = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\noindent
(\citeNP[pp.~15--22]{atkin14}; \citeNP[p.~282]{rub14})

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use your example and apply the \citeA command it raises the error "Undefined control sequence". What's the reason behind this?

Comment: @kexxcream - The option `natbibapa` instructs `apacite` to define `natbib`-style citation macros. I'll revise the answer so that you can keep working with `\citeA`, etc.

Comment: Highly appreciated, and thanks for bringing it to my attention to include MWE. Will consider this carefully for the next post.