# Multiple citations with multiple comments

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

I often use multiple citations to blocks I write. So one example could be:

```
This is one part of my text \cite{cit01, cit02, cit03}.
```

Resulting to:

```
This is one part of my text (Kaplan 1996; Norton 1982; Hemming 2002).
```

Now I'd like to provide the pages within those three books as well. So I use:

```
This is one part of my text \cite[pp. 25 f]{cit01}\cite[pp. 55 f]{cit02}\cite[pp. 26 f]{cit03}.
```

Resulting to:

```
This is one part of my text (Kaplan 1996, pp. 25 f)(Norton 1982, pp. 55 f)(Hemming 2002, pp. 26 f).
```

But, this separated citation isn't what I really want. I'd rather have a result that looks like this. Hence, everything with one rounded brackets:

```
This is one part of my text (Kaplan 1996, pp. 25 f; Norton 1982, pp. 55 f; Hemming 2002, pp. 26 f).
```

Is that possible?

**EDIT:**

I use `bibtex`.

**EDIT 2:**
I use `bibtex` together with `biblatex`.

Comment: Please tell us which citation management package (if any...) you employ.

Comment: If you use `biblatex` you can use `\cites[25\psq]{cit01}[55\psq]{cit02}[26\psq]{cit03}` (note the **`s`** and the lack of "pp."s as well as that the `f` has been replaced with `\psq`).

Comment: Do you use BibTeX with `biblatex` or `natbib` or `cite`? An [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) would guarantee that we are all talking about the same thing.

Comment: @moewe Added EDIT 2.

Comment: @moewe Your example worked.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910/35864

Comment: Why do you use "pp." AND "f" or "ff"? Doesn't it say the same thing? Or what does it mean to use one or the other or both?

Comment: @thymaro pp means there are following pages after page X, and f means there will be one single following page.

Comment: Just like I thought, then, but then you could just omit the pp and just write either f or ff, which would absolutely be sufficient and also look better. (which is what moewe does in the answer, btw)

Comment: @thymaro You could indeed just use pp or f. In the end it's a matter of style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `biblatex` you'll want to use the multicite commands, see §3.8.3 *Qualified Citation Lists* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
\cites[25\psq]{sigfridsson}[55\psq]{worman}[26\psq]{geer}
```

In full

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  sequens   = {f\adddot},
  sequentes = {ff\adddot},
}

\begin{document}
\parencites[25\psq]{sigfridsson}[55\psq]{worman}[26\psq]{geer}
\end{document}
```

Note how the "pp." can and should be dropped in the postnote argument if you use `\psq` instead of `f.` and `\psqq` instead of `ff.`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `natbib` citation management package, you could employ three `\citealt` directives encased in a common `( ... )` set of parentheses. E.g., something like the following:

[image]

If you want commas between the authors' names and the years, simply use `\citealp` instead of `\citealt`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{cit01,author="Kaplan" ,year=1996,title="X"}
@misc{cit02,author="Norton" ,year=1982,title="Y"}
@misc{cit03,author="Hemming",year=2002,title="Z"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % select a suitable bibliography style

\begin{document}
\dots\ (\citealt[pp.~25\,f]{cit01}; \citealt[pp.~55\,f]{cit02}; 
\citealt[pp.~26\,f]{cit03}).
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```