# Biblatex: chicago-authordate with multiple sources and specifications

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago, multiple-citations

Using `biblatex` with the `chicago-authordate` style, I want to typeset a citation with multiple sources and page specifications as "(Hacking 1975, p. 49; Hald 1990, p. 31)".

Ideally, it would something like the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @book{hald,
    title={Reference},
    author={Hald},
    year={1990},
}
@book{hacking,
    title={Reference},
    author={Hacking},
    year={1975},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \citep[p. 49; p.31]{hacking,hald}
\end{document}
```

The MWE however produces the citation typeset as

> (Hacking 1975; Hald 1990, p. 49; p.31)

rather than

> (Hacking 1975, p. 49; Hald 1990, p. 31)

Can I have the wanted typesetting using either the `biblatex` or the `biblatex-chicago` package?

Comment: `\parencites[49]{hacking}[31]{hald}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910/35864

Comment: Please note that styles of the `biblatex-chicago` bundle should usually be loaded through the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago` and not via `biblatex`. Replace `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}` with `\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}`

Comment: \parencites was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!
I wasn't aware of the multiple cites functionality.