# Multiple footfullcite with page numbers

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, multiple-citations

I want to use footfullcite for two citations after a paragraph. But the citations should be same footnote. The issue I am having is that I also want page numbers attached to each citation.

In this MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article1,
    title = {Article1},
    author = {Alpha, A},
    journal= {Prestigious Journal},
    year={2021}
}
@article{article2,
    title = {Article2},
    author = {Beta, B},
    journal= {Prestigious Journal},
    year={2021}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\footfullcite[p.15]{article1} \footfullcite[p.20]{article2}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have as a footnote.

1 A Alpha. “Article1”. In: *Prestigious Journal* (2021), p.15.; B Beta. “Article2”. In: *Prestigious Journal* (2021), p.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is a job for the multicite version of your cite command, see [Multiple citations with pages using BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910/35864). But there is no multicite version of `\footfullcite`, so we have to define one with `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand` before we can use it.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footfullcites}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\footfullcite}{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footfullcites[380]{sigfridsson}[20]{worman}
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096- 987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1> 3.0.CO;2- P, p. 380; Nancy Worman. The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002, p. 20.]

Note that you don't need to (and indeed should not) give the "p." prefix in the postnote argument. `biblatex` automatically adds the appropriate page prefix ("p."/"pp.") for numeric postnotes.

---

I think there is no multicite version of `\footfullcite`, because the command is supposed to be used as a one-off. If you want all citations to be long citations in the footnote, a `verbose` style might be more appropriate.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocites[380]{sigfridsson}[20]{worman}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `\fullcite` commands in a single `\footnote`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article1,
    title = {Article1},
    author = {Alpha, A},
    journal= {A Journal},
    year={2021}
}
@article{article2,
    title = {Article2},
    author = {Beta, B},
    journal= {A Journal},
    year={2021}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[textheight=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
The moon is made of cheese\footnote{\fullcite[p.15]{article1}.; \fullcite[p.20]{article2}.}.
\end{document}
```

[image]