# Citation Style: (vgl. author year, page; a y, p)

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations, styles

Most of my citations are only from one source so \parencite[vgl.][page]{x} gives me what I want. but there is a paragraph where I cited from two differents sources. I don't know how to get (vgl. author year, page; a y, p). the style is \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

Comment: pls help how to

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you want, but it sounds like you might be looking for multicite commands. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910/35864. You might want to try `\parencites(vgl.)()[380]{sigfridsson}[24]{worman}`.

Comment: i love you @moewe

Comment: I'll take that outpouring of affection to mean that the multicite command is indeed what you are after. Closing as duplicate. Glad I could help.