# Multiple footnote citations with page numbers using BibLateX

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, biber, apa7

For my thesis, I need to present the references in full as footnotes every time the document is presented in the text.

For that, I've been using BibLatex with the following options:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,language=english]{biblatex}
```

In the text, when necessary, insert a reference, the command I'm using is `\footfullcite{ref}`. However, sometimes I need to insert multiple references in the same footnote, and for that, the command is `\footfullcite{ref1,ref2,ref3}`.

It works perfectly when I'm referencing articles.

The problem is when I need to indicate the page of the document, like a book. The command `\footfullcite[p. x]{ref}` works perfectly when only one reference is indicated, but when indicating multiple references, I can't indicate the page for one specific reference.

If I try to use the command `\footfullcite[p. x]{ref1,ref2,ref3}`, the number of the page appears at the end of all references, independently of which works it refers to.

I have tried to adapt a solution like the one present [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18910/multiple-citations-with-pages-using-biblatex), but it didn't work.

A MWE of what I'm trying:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{test,
        title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure Alcohols},
        volume = {71},
        number = {17},
        journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
        author = {Test T.},
        month = aug,
        year = {2006},
        pages = {6333--6445}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{abntex2}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    First\footfullcite{test}, second\footfullcite{test} and third time.\footfullcite{test}
    Multiple times.\footfullcite{test,test,test}
    Multiple times with page number.\footfullcite[p. 15]{test,test,test}
    \end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

However, I would like to insert the page number on the second reference, for example, and not at the end of all references.

Could someone please help me? Thank you!!

PS: On my system, I'm using the command `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,language=english]{biblatex}`, but for some reason I don't know, when I try to use this command in the MWE, the references don't appear correctly.

Comment: See `multicite` in the biblatex manual (`texdoc biblatex`).

Comment: @Cicada thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it didn't help much.

The `multicite` options don't work in my case, as there's not a multicite version of `\footfullcite`.

If I try to use the `\footcitetexts` command, I am able to insert the number of the page correctly linked with the work I choose. But this option does not provide me the full information of the references, as I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multicite commands to give multiple citations with separate `postnote` (page ranges). By default there is no multicite version of `\footfullcite`, presumably because it was not envisioned that `\footfullcite` would be your go-to citation command, but it is not too hard to make a multicite version of it

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

% just for the example
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{annotation}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footfullcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footfullcite}{\multicitedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \footfullcites[380]{sigfridsson}[12]{worman}[51]{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E., & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. https://doi.org/10.1002(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P p. 380; Worman, N. (2002). The cast of character: Style in Greek literature. University of Texas Press, p. 12; Geer, I. de. (1985). Earl, saint, bishop, skald – and music: The Orkney Earldom of the twelfth century. A musicological study [Doctoral dissertation, Uppsala Universitet]. Uppsala, p. 51]

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found:

Although the BibLaTeX manual refers that by default it will not sort citations if multiple entry keys are passed to a citation command, it kept sorting the entries cited following the default sorting for the bibliography (NTY).

To change that, I had to force it to disregard any sorting order, adding the option `sortcites=false`.

Now the BibLateX is called with the following options:

`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, sortcites=false, language=english]{biblatex}`

This allows me to keep using the `\footfullcite` command, and I just have to order the entries cited in order to leave the one that will present the page number as the last.

The command will be `\footfullcite[p. 15]{test1,test2,test3}` to insert the page number to the reference #3, or `\footfullcite[p. 15]{test3,test2,test1}` to insert the page number to the reference #1.

I am aware that this is not a complete solution, as if it is necessary to insert different page numbers to different entries, this solution will not work.

Comment: While it is the `biblatex` core default to have `sortcites=false,`, styles you load may change this. `style=apa,` sets `sortcites=true,` overriding the `biblatex` core default.

Comment: Thank you very much @moewe for your comment and elegant solution. It helped a lot!