# Problem with commas in intext references when using \citealp command (Biblatex and Bath style)

Tags: biblatex

I have been writing for a dissertation and struggling with referencing styles. As we know, some unis and departments are very specific in what they want...

I use the "Bath" style from `biblatex` and `natbib` commands to cite. Most of the time the command `\citep` does the work for my in-line citations, however I sometimes need to use multiple references with different page references eg.

> (Last Name 2050, 12; Last name 2 2030, 40).

I generally do that using the `\citealp` command:

```
(\citealp[12]{last_name_fake_2050}; \citealp[40]{last_name_2_fake_2030}).
```

**My problem** My university is asking a style which is (Last name year, page; last name year, page). For the `\citep` command and single references, I had managed with the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=bath,backend=biber,maxcitenames=2,natbib=true,uniquelist=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite, bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However, with the `\citealp` command, I end up with

> (Last Name,2050, 12; Last name 2,2030, 40)

and I'd like to remove the commas between the last name and the date as I had done with the `\citep` command. I would need about how to do this.

As an illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=bath,backend=biber,maxcitenames=2,natbib=true,uniquelist=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite, bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}


\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
when I use citep command
\citep[12]{last_name_fake_2050}

when I use citealp
(\citealp[12]{last_name_fake_2050}; \citealp[40]{last_name_2_fake_2030})

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with these two entries in the references.bib

```
@article{last_name_2_fake_2030,
    title = {Fake article 2},
    author = {Last name 2, First},
    year = {2030},
}

@article{last_name_fake_2050,
    title = {Fake article 1},
    author = {Last Name, First},
    year = {2050},
}
```

Comment: Would `\citealt` instead of `\citealp` be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, indeed, thanks for suggesting this! It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `biblatex`'s multicite features, then there is no need to fiddle around with several cite commands and manual parentheses. See [Multiple citations with pages using BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910/35864).

The multicite commands are not available with the `natbib` compatibility names, so you will have to use `\parencites` or `\autocites`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=bath, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false, uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite, bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    
\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite[12]{sigfridsson}
  ipsum \autocites[12]{sigfridsson}[40]{worman}
    
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, 12) ipsum (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, 12; Worman 2002, 40)]

---

If you insist on using `\citealp`, you can solve the issue by noting that `\citealp` is basically just `\cite`, so that you need to change the `nameyeardelim` delimiter not only in the `parencite`, but also in the `cite` context.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber, 
  style=bath,
  maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=false, uniquename=false,
  natbib=true, 
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[cite, parencite, bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    
\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite[12]{sigfridsson}
  ipsum (\citealp[12]{sigfridsson}; \citealp[40]{worman})
    
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives the same output.