# APA7 citation style - pages of different articles

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

My code example:

```latex
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
too \parencite{vonDavier2011,Lassen2006}.  Further evidence comes from
\end{document}
```

My problem is that I need as an ouput e.g.:

> (Lassen et al., 2006, p. 5; von Davier et al., 2011, p. 12)

and not

> (Lassen et al., 2006; von Davier et al., 2011).

So I have to cite the pages of different articles. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple citations each of which needs its own postnote argument, you can use `biblatex`'s multicite commands. Instead of `\parencite` use `\parencites` and put every entry key in a pair of curly braces of its own. Then you can give each entry its own postnote with square brackets as usual.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\shorttitle{Short}% to keep apa7 happy

\begin{document}
too \parencites[380]{sigfridsson}[25]{worman}.  Further evidence comes from
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, p. 380; Worman, 2002, p. 25)]

Unless your system is really old, you shouldn't be needing the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`. The `biblatex` options `sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,` are also no longer required for `biblatex-apa` (the `sorting=nyt,` would even be detrimental, because it switches to a generic name-year-title sorting that does not follow APA guidelines).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910/35864.