Combining two citations with reference text
I want to cite two sources together and want it to appear something like [S1, Thm. 8.1.2, S2, Lem. 2.2]
Currently I have something like this:
assume ... so that can apply the Girsanov theorem on manifolds, e.g. see \cite[Thm. 8.1.2]{hsu2002stochastic}, \cite[Lem. 2.2]{zhang2007girsanov}.

This shows up like [S1, Thm. 8.1.2], [S2, Lem. 2.2], but I want something like: [S1, Thm. 8.1.2, S2, Lem. 2.2]. Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?
Citations: 

@book{hsu2002stochastic,
  title={Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds},
  author={Hsu, E.P.},
  isbn={9780821808023},
  lccn={2001046052},
  series={Graduate studies in mathematics},
  url={https://books.google.com/books?id=GDEPCgAAQBAJ},
  year={2002},
  publisher={American Mathematical Society}
}

@article{zhang2007girsanov,
author = {Jingxiao Zhang and D. Kannan},
title = {A Girsanov Type Theorem on the Path Space Over a Compact Riemannian Manifold},
journal = {Stochastic Analysis and Applications},
volume = {25},
number = {3},
pages = {667--678},
year = {2007},
publisher = {Taylor \& Francis},
doi = {10.1080/07362990701283003},
URL = { https://doi.org/10.1080/07362990701283003
},
eprint = { 
https://doi.org/10.1080/07362990701283003
}
}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... Do not forget to add the used bib entries too!

Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18910/multiple-citations-with-pages-using-biblatex (second answer) would work?

@Marijn thanks! that worked

@optimal_transport_fan good, then let's close this question as a duplicate.
